# excel: sum of several searchcriteria

Tags: excel

I am struggling to get the sum of several searchcriteria. Example:
I want to get the sum of `/blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen` and `/blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen/amp`

[image]

I tried with this but getting parsing error because of the part `B28 & /amp` for finding `/blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen/amp`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(BlogartikelErfolg!B:B,(BlogartikelErfolg!A:A=B28)*(BlogartikelErfolg!A:A=B28&/amp))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have in an easily extendable OR form as show below:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(BlogartikelErfolg!B:B, BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,{"phrase1","phrase2"}))
```

Or you can add two `SUMIF` together:

```
=SUMIF(BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,"phrase1",BlogartikelErfolg!B:B) + SUMIF(BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,"phrase2",BlogartikelErfolg!B:B)
```

Note that literal strings are wrapped in `""`. You replace `phrase1` and `phrase2` with your search terms.

E.g.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(BlogartikelErfolg!B:B, BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,{"/blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen","/blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen/amp"}))
```

---

**Holding search strings in cells:**

If you want to pull from two cells then use

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(BlogartikelErfolg!B:B, BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,E1:E2))
```

Here E1 and E2 hold the strings to search for.

[image: Data]

If you must use a single cell, `E1`, and then add "/amp" onto this, as per comments, then consider the following:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(BlogartikelErfolg!B:B, BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(E1 &"," &E1 &"/amp",CHAR(44), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")))
```

I find this harder to read though.

[image: Data]

I assume that `","` doesn't appear in your strings. If it does then swop the delimiter used here `E1 & "," &` , and update the `CHAR` reference to it here `CHAR(44)`, in the `FILTERXML`.

Comment: thanks, the problem is, how to look dynamically for that? I have 
"blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen" in another cell. So I can look for this. But how to look for "blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen/amp"? This is not working: "B28 & /amp" ... B28 is the cell where "blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen" is located

Comment: I have added a bottom version where search strings are held in cells.

Comment: b28 & "/amp" results to /blog/beckenschiefstand-uebungen/amp
but this is creating a parsing error:
=SUMMEWENN(BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,"b28",BlogartikelErfolg!B:B) + summewenn(BlogartikelErfolg!A:A,"b28 & "/amp"",BlogartikelErfolg!B:B)

Comment: Why are you doing & "/amp" ? Why not have this in the actual search string? See my image above.

Comment: because I have about 300 cells with urls without the /amp.. I have no cell with /amp version

Comment: Use the column next to these cells and simply add on "/amp". You need to create a valid array for OR condition. Easiest way as shown above.

Comment: I added a final version which does what you want. Let me know if you need it explaining.